# Build an RPM for a specific minor version of RH

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

I need an RPM built for a specific minor version of RH, so that it only installs on that minor version (ex RHEL 6.4) and not on other minor versions like RHEL 6.6.

Also when rpm/yum installs this pkg on a platform it was not meant for (RHEL 6.6 in the example above), the installation should continue for the rest of the pkgs to install.

I looked over `/usr/lib/rpm/rpmrc` but I could not find anything that I can use.

Answer (score 0):

With the rpm `%pre` script (see http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-scripts.html) you can check the system before the rpm installation (for exemple the `/etc/redhat-release file`). But I do not think you can do more than make the installation fail.

A possible way to just skip installation on unwanted system is to build the rpm in a way that the installed files are put in a temporary folder. Then the `%post` installation script can check the system version and if needed copy the file to the right location.
You'll have to make sure that the un-installation also behave correctly by using the `%preun` or `%postun` scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You could put a Requires: for your redhat-release package, with a specific version, say, 6.4.

I'd check all the metadata for the redhat-release RPM, and see what's appropriate